# Build Error while building aperturejs

Tags: maven

I am trying to build aperturejs with Readme.md instructions.

I cloned the repository and tried the command mvn clean install in the root directory of ApertureJs.

I got the following Build Error as in the screenshot,
[image]

I am using the latest version of Maven - 3.3.9

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. The issue is solved. I posted this issue to Uncharted Software's Salt Repository and exactly like Clement Said, I was trying to access a repository that no more has access publicly. Therefore they gave a workaround.

It is available here -> https://github.com/unchartedsoftware/aperturejs/issues/22

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the error in your console, I could feel that you are not authorized to access the particular repository, which is shown in your console.

Copy the repository url and try it from a browser - hope you will not be able to access the repository, since you are not authorized.

Raise appropriate access and after getting access, then try mvn clean install.

Below is the Quick fix till the time you get the access:

Copy and Paste the respective jar/pom/folder from your colleague machine, in your .m2/repository/...

Run the mvn clean install with -o option so that it will look into your local repository for building your application